# What is the antecedent of 'where' in this sentence?

Tags: antecedents

[In the following sentence](https://www.newarab.com/features/fans-flock-first-ever-comic-con-saudi-arabia), what is the antecedent? I thought it might be **YouTube**, but there's also a possibility of it being **Internet platforms**.

> "You're free here," said Dainiy. "You are yourself." He said he wore
> the horse head because it is a character on the channel he operates on
> YouTube, one of the many popular Internet platforms **where** Saudis
> live much of their lives to escape from the strictures of a rigid
> society.][1](https://www.newarab.com/features/fans-flock-first-ever-comic-con-saudi-arabia)

Answer (score 7):

Structurally, it's ambiguous whether "where" refers to "YouTube" or "platforms" because both fit, but "platforms" appears better for two reasons: it's closer to "where" in the sentence, and there's no comma after "platforms", which we'd expect if "one of the many popular Internet platforms" was a phrase on its own modifying "YouTube".

Semantically, "platforms" makes a lot more sense too. If "where" referred to "YouTube", that would mean "one of the many popular Internet platforms" alone modified "YouTube", but these days it's unnecessary to tell your readers that YouTube is a popular Internet platform -- everybody knows that already. It does, however, make sense to tell the readers that YouTube is one of the many popular Internet platforms that Saudis use to escape their rigid society.

So the answer is "platforms", not "YouTube".

Answer (score 1):

A comma after "platforms" would make "YouTube" the antecedent "where".  As it stands, the sentence seems to mean that Saudis spend their lives not on YouTube alone, but on many different social media, internet "platforms".